# MSSQL and Post Variables

Tags: php, sql-server, loops, foreach, var-dump

It may have been a bit since I've worked with this and I think I have been looking at this one to long. Just can't see what I am obviously missing.

I am attempting to query records assigned to terminated team members and within that query perform a second query with displays employed team members in a select menu. Allowing records from terminated team members to be assigned to employed team members.

I am working with a form that passing the following values to POST:

```
            <?php
            //Loop Through all records in Select Query
            foreach ($TMReservesResult as $Record=>$Value){
        ?>  
            <?php //var_dump($Value); ?>
            <td><?php echo $Value['Company Name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Value['PhoneNumber']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Value['State']; ?></td>

        <?php
            //STRIP TIME FROM DATE STRING
            $str = $Value['CallDate'];
            $res = $Value['Call Back Date'];
        ?>  

            <td><?php echo substr($str, 0, 11); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo substr($res, 0, 11); ?></td>
            <td>
            <center>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                 <select class="form-control" name="UserName">
                                    <?php foreach($FindActiveTMNamesResults AS $TMNames=>$TMs) { ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $TMs['UserName']; ?>"><?php echo $TMs['UserName']; ?></option>
                                    <?php } ?> 
                                 </select>
                           </div>
                    </div>
           </center>                         
        </td>
        </tr>

        <input type="hidden" name="ContactID[]" value="<?php echo $Value["ContactID"]; ?>" />

        <?php } ?>
```

Processing the POST values:

```
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
            //update Employee Info
            $ContactID =  Escape_Function($_POST["ContactID"]);
            $UserName = Escape_Function(($_POST["UserName"]));

            foreach($ContactID as $id){

            //Update Query
            $UpdateEmployeeQuery = 'UPDATE [ACR Contact Management].[dbo].[Contacts] SET [LeadGenerator] = \'' . $UserName . '\' WHERE [ContactID] = \'' . $id . '\'';
                $UpdateEmployeeResult = $DB->query($UpdateEmployeeQuery);

    } 

 }

?>
```

And the results of

```
<?php 

var_dump($UpdateEmployeeQuery);

?>
```

> string(113) "UPDATE [ACR Contact Management].[dbo].[Contacts] SET
>   [LeadGenerator] = 'sbarnes' WHERE [ContactID] = '1362718628'"
>   string(113) "UPDATE [ACR Contact Management].[dbo].[Contacts] SET
>   [LeadGenerator] = 'sbarnes' WHERE [ContactID] = '1362703257'"
>   string(113) "UPDATE [ACR Contact Management].[dbo].[Contacts] SET
>   [LeadGenerator] = 'sbarnes' WHERE [ContactID] = '1364930874'"
>   string(113) "UPDATE [ACR Contact Management].[dbo].[Contacts] SET
>   [LeadGenerator] = 'sbarnes' WHERE [ContactID] = '1364930900'"
>   string(113) "UPDATE [ACR Contact Management].[dbo].[Contacts] SET
>   [LeadGenerator] = 'sbarnes' WHERE [ContactID] = '1364930976'"

It appears that my ID loop is working correctly, however, the loop (or lack of) is only grabbing the last record terminate team member name.

What am I missing? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You should use prepared statements, not escape functions.  I don't know what Escape_Function() does, but it seems strange you would pass an arrays to it.

Comment: Are you sure the closing braces are right in that loop? It looks to me just on the basis of what you posted there might be one missing after the foreach...?

Comment: @Devon Thank you, will give prepared statements a try.

Comment: @DavidW Nice find. It actually is correct in my editor I just did not copy the last bracket to my example. Will edit. Thank you!

Comment: @DerekManson: It's taking only last username? Correct? Is this your problem?

Comment: @NanaPartykar Yes that is correct. I'm just not seeing what I have done incorrect.

Comment: Well, where do you try to get a  different username?  You seem to be using the same variable that doesn't ever get reassigned.

Comment: @Devon A look creates the record and within that loop is a select option with the usernames to update the record.

Comment: Where does `$UserName` ever change in your loop?  It'd be like using `$ContactID` instead of `$id`.  `$id` gets reassigned every iteration because of the foreach arguments, but `$ContactID` and `$UserName` don't change.

Comment: You might capture the return value of $DB->query and see if any of the updates return FALSE. I think 'query' returns TRUE or FALSE depending on whether execution occurred without or with error..., then you could look at $DB->error for a message or more detail..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`<select class="form-control" name="UserName">`

To

`<select class="form-control" name="UserName[]">`

**Page** (Where you are processing the POST values)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_POST["ContactID"]);$i++){

    $id = Escape_Function($_POST["ContactID"][$i]);
    $UserName = Escape_Function($_POST["UserName"][$i]);

    $UpdateEmployeeQuery = 'UPDATE [ACR Contact Management].[dbo].[Contacts] SET [LeadGenerator] = \'' . $UserName . '\' WHERE [ContactID] = \'' . $id . '\'';
    $UpdateEmployeeResult = $DB->query($UpdateEmployeeQuery);
  }
}?>
```

You are passing ContactId as array but, not passing username as array type. So, it's taking the option selected of last dropdown. Change it as array type and loop to iterate each and every record.

Comment: I did attempt setting the array of UserName[] value but was clearly not processing correctly. This did the trick and I learned a thing or two. Thank you good sir!